# What types of GraphQL variable are allowed?

Tags: graphql

GraphQL common practice, especially over HTTP, is that there is a `query` parameter, an optional `operationName` and an optional JSON object providing `variables`.

All examples of the `variables` parameter I've seen are simple JSON objects:

```
{
  "var1": "value1",
  "var2": 2
}
```

Each key has a simple JSON type value, such as a numeric or a string.

Can GraphQL variable values be more expansive than this, with deeper mixes of arrays and objects?

```
{
  "var1": "value1",
  "var2": {
    "name": "My Name",
    "numbers": [1, 5, 11, 10]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, however, you're going to want me make sure you have a matching input type in your schema. So to accept an input with a structure like the one in `var2`, you'd need something like this:

```
input VarInput {
  name: String
  numbers: [Int]
}
```

Then, for the type definition of your query/mutation...

```
type Query {
  foo (var1: String, var2: VarInput): Foo
}
```

Your resolver can then fetch `var2` like any other argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I'm willing to accept it as correct. I wonder, though, if you have any more information about how the server is expected to coerce the variables to GraphQL types?

Comment: @BenCox Whatever implementation of GraphQL you are using will handle resolving the inputs to their correct type, again, based on the information you provide through the type definitions in your schema. There's no additional step required on the server side if that's what you're asking.